# How to convert a sequence of points to a sequence of ranges?

Tags: c#, collections

For example, I have a sequence of points

List points = new List {0, 1, 2, 4, 5 ,7};

And I want to convert it to a sequence of ranges (My type `Range(leftPoint, rightPoint)`). For the example, results are

> `List<Range>` ranges: {0, 1} {1, 2} {2, 4} {4, 5} {5, 7}

Comment: When you use the word point, do you mean a System.Drawing.point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a simple for-loop?

```
for(var i = 0; i < points.Count() - 1; i++)
  ranges.Add(new Range(points[i], points[i+1]))
```

Comment: Indeed, for-loop is the way to go if indexes matter.

Answer (score 5):

You could use LINQ (presuming the list is already sorted):

```
List<Range> rangeList = Enumerable.Range(0, points.Count - 1)
    .Select(i => new Range(points[i], points[i + 1]))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<int> points = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
        List<List<int>> listOfRanges = new List<List<int>>();
        listOfRanges.Add(points.GetRange(0, 2));
        listOfRanges.Add(points.GetRange(1, 2));
        listOfRanges.Add(points.GetRange(2, 2));
        listOfRanges.Add(points.GetRange(3, 2));
        listOfRanges.Add(points.GetRange(4, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over it like so:

```
List<int> points = new List {0, 1, 2, 4, 5 ,7};
List<Range> listOfRanges = new List<Range>();
int index = 0
foreach (int value in points) {
    listOfRanges.add(new Range(points[i], points[i+1]));
    index++;
}
```

You might get a null comparison exception on the last iteration of the loop as points[i+1] doesn't exist - if so just handle this with a simple if statement.

This is assuming by points you mean a list of integers. I'll update if I find you meant something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to zip the two lists that we get when we:

1. Take everything except the last element
2. Take everything except the first element

These correspond to (in the case of your example):

0, 1, 2, 4, 5

1, 2, 4, 5 ,7

Here is how you do it in code:

```
var result =
   points
   .Take(points.Count - 1) //points except last element
   .Zip(
        points.Skip(1), //points except first element
        (l, r) => new Range(l, r))
   .ToList();
```